# how to access joomla database for run this code

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

```
<?php
require_once('./common/connector/scheduler_connector.php');
$res=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("JOOMLA DATABASE");
    $conn = new SchedulerConnector($res);
    $scheduler->render_table("events","event_id","start_date,end_date,event_name,details");
?>
```

its contain 2 php file it create hourly timeline when i connect it to same table in another database it works, but when i connect it to joomla database result nothing, someone can help me to improve it as joomla style

Comment: Look at joomla config file and fill your DB connection string same as config file.

Comment: config all is the same localhost  root  password i jusr import one joomla tables to other database it works but when i use joomla database with the same table it not works!! for example when i export (nt29v_rsform_submission_values)table from joomla database and import it to test database and change mysql_select_db("test") it works but (nt29v_rsform_submission_values)table in joomla database and change mysql_select_db("joomladb")  show nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the code as the table name seems incorrect. I dont know about the SchedulerConnector class but i guess first variable is table name

```
$scheduler->render_table("events","event_id","start_date,end_date,event_name,details");
```

You need to give the correct table name with extension like

```
$scheduler->render_table("nt29v_events","event_id","start_date,end_date,event_name,details");
```

you include `nt29v_` in table name if this is your table extension; as you are connecting to Joomla database externally.

I checked the class and I got this

render_table
configures connector and retrieves data from single table.

```
$conn->render_table($table,$id,$text,$extra,$relation);
```

Parameters:

```
$table - the name of a table.
$id - the name of the id field.
$text - a comma separated list of data fields.
$extra - a comma separated list of extra fields, optional.
$relation_id - used for building hierarchy in case of Tree and TreeGrid.
```

S what I guessed was correct
Ref: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__connector_object_methods.html#rendertable

Comment: yea i know i actually using one of table of joomla (rs forms) component (nt29v_rsform_submission_values) and i use query like this :            $conn->render_table("select  submissionId as id, (select STR_TO_DATE(t1.fieldvalue, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') from nt29v_rsform_submission_values t1 where t1.submissionId = t.submissionId  and t1.fieldName = 'ubergabe') as start_date, (select STR_TO_DATE(t2.fieldvalue, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') from nt29v_rsform_submission_values t2 where t2.submissionId = t.submissionId  and....)

Comment: it works ok when i move this table to test database and change mysql_select_db("test") but in joomla database with same table with same structure with same perfix and mysql_select_db("joomladb") its show nothing!!!!